# Saving enum type into database returns null mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When I'm trying to save enum type from dropdownList into database and the saved value is null using code first. Can someone help me please?

My controller :

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  return View(db.Users.ToList());
}

public ActionResult Create()
{
  User model = new User();
  IEnumerable<Proov.Models.User.UserType> userTypes = Enum
    .GetValues(typeof(Proov.Models.User.UserType))
    .Cast<Proov.Models.User.UserType>();
  model.TypeList = from user in userTypes
                   select new SelectListItem
                   {
                     Text = user.ToString(),
                     Value = ((int)user).ToString()
                   };
  return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(User user)
{   
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {      
    db.Users.Add(user);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
  }
  return View(user);
}
```

View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
  <label>Set a type for your user :</label><br />
  @Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.UserId, Model.TypeList) 
  <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
  </p>
}
```

Comment: And what is your problem then?

Comment: Anyuthing i select from dropdown list is a null value

Comment: Are you sure the user type value is populated on postback? Show us your view perhaps?

Comment: Shouldn't the view say `model => model.UsertypeId` (or equivalent)?

Comment: So i need separate id for the enum ? i have constructor in my model class which passes the IENumberable<SelectListItem>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view code is incorrect. You are assigning the dropdown list to UserId instead of the respective user type property. For example:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.UserTypeId, Model.TypeList) 
<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
</p>
```

Comment: If you want to bind to an enum, then make property `UserTypeId`  typeof `UserType` and then `select new SelectListItem { Text = user.ToString(),  Value = user.ToString() };` - the `ModelBinder` will take care of the rest.

Answer (score 0):

If you use ASP.NET MVC 5.1 or higher you could use:

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.YOURENUM)
```